QGIS - list/string comparison using SQLite
I'm using SQLite to process multiple queries while working with SpatiaLite layers.
I need to identify which string has been added to a list after updating the layer. Currently, my approach involves saving the value of the NEW entity in another table as a workaround. However, I'm exploring alternative methods.
For example, I'm working with the field "ESPECE":
OLD.ESPECE = '{Lythrum thymifolia, Ophioglossum vulgatum}'
NEW.ESPECE = '{Lythrum thymifolia, Ophioglossum vulgatum, Poa pratensis}'

In this case, the desired result is 'Poa pratensis'.
I have attempted various methods, but none have been successful so far. Here are a few examples:
    WITH RECURSIVE
    chaine_initiale(elements) AS (
      SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia,Ophioglossum vulgatum}'
    ),
    chaine_finale(elements) AS (
      SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia,Ophioglossum vulgatum,Poa pratensis}'
    ),
    split(reste, element) AS (
      SELECT 
        substr(trim(replace(replace(elements, '{', ''), '}', '')), instr(trim(replace(replace(elements, '{', ''), '}', '')), ',') + 1),
        substr(trim(replace(replace(elements, '{', ''), '}', '')), 1, instr(trim(replace(replace(elements, '{', ''), '}', '')), ',') - 1)
      FROM chaine_finale
      UNION ALL
      SELECT
        substr(reste, instr(reste, ',') + 1),
        substr(reste, 1, instr(reste, ',') - 1)
      FROM split
      WHERE instr(reste, ',') > 0
    )
    SELECT DISTINCT trim(element) AS nouvel_element
    FROM split
    WHERE trim(element) != '' AND trim(element) NOT IN (
      SELECT trim(value)
      FROM chaine_initiale,
           json_each('["' || replace(replace(chaine_initiale.elements, '{', ''), '}', '') || '"]')
    )
    LIMIT 1;


WITH 
chaine_initiale(elements) AS (
  SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia,Ophioglossum vulgatum}'
),
chaine_finale(elements) AS (
  SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia,Ophioglossum vulgatum,Poa pratensis}'
)
SELECT 
  CASE 
    WHEN instr(chaine_finale.elements, 'Poa pratensis') > 0 
     AND instr(chaine_initiale.elements, 'Poa pratensis') = 0 
    THEN 'Poa pratensis'
    ELSE NULL
  END AS nouvel_element
FROM chaine_initiale, chaine_finale;


WITH RECURSIVE
chaine_initiale(elements) AS (
  SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia,Ophioglossum vulgatum}'
),
chaine_finale(elements) AS (
  SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia,Ophioglossum vulgatum,Poa pratensis}'
),
split(str, element, rest) AS (
  SELECT 
    elements,
    trim(substr(elements, 2, instr(substr(elements, 2), ',') - 1)),
    trim(substr(elements, instr(elements, ',') + 1, length(elements) - instr(elements, ',') - 1))
  FROM chaine_finale
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    rest,
    CASE 
      WHEN instr(rest, ',') = 0 THEN rest
      ELSE trim(substr(rest, 1, instr(rest, ',') - 1))
    END,
    CASE 
      WHEN instr(rest, ',') = 0 THEN ''
      ELSE trim(substr(rest, instr(rest, ',') + 1))
    END
  FROM split
  WHERE rest != ''
)
SELECT element AS nouvel_element
FROM split
WHERE element NOT IN (
  SELECT trim(value)
  FROM chaine_initiale,
       json_each('["' || replace(replace(chaine_initiale.elements, '{', ''), '}', '') || '"]')
)
LIMIT 1;



WITH 
liste1(elements) AS (
  SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia,Ophioglossum vulgatum}'
),
liste2(elements) AS (
  SELECT '{Lythrum thymifolia}'
)
SELECT DISTINCT trim(value) AS nouvel_element
FROM liste1, json_each('["' || REPLACE(REPLACE(liste1.elements, '{', ''), '}', '') || '"]')
WHERE trim(value) NOT IN (
  SELECT trim(value)
  FROM liste2, json_each('["' || REPLACE(REPLACE(liste2.elements, '{', ''), '}', '') || '"]')
)
LIMIT 1;



I'm not sure this is the right place for this Q which is 99% SQL and maybe 1% GIS. There's two ways to make this a lot easier: 1. normalise your data so that there's another table in a 1:N relationship with OLD that stores the ESPECE values, one per row, or 2. use a JSON data type in your SQLite which lets you do arrays in columns. eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005231/how-to-store-array-in-one-column-in-sqlite3

Alright, I created a secondary table that is used to temporary save the last entered value. I use it to the next steps of the process and everything is working well now.
